# "sets A and B" or "A and B sets"

Tags: grammatical-number

"sets A and B" or "A and B sets" is the same meaning in a statement? For examples:

We combine sets A and B. or
We combine A and B sets.

Can anyone help to differentiate it? Tq.

Answer (score 1):

In English-language mathematics, you would use the first one:

> We combine sets *A* and *B*.

Similar English conventions would say that we use

> We visited the cities London, Paris and Rome.

and not

> *We visited London, Paris and Rome cities.

Comment: How about in international relations. E.g. "A relation between the USA and Russia is a relation neutral". or "A relation between the USA and Russia is a neutral relation". Please help. tq.

Comment: Another an example: "In 10-year observation period, the USA and Russia are in relations friendly and neutral." or "In 10-year observation period, the USA and Russia are in friendly and neutral relations.". please help to clarify. tq.

Answer (score 0):

I should think *we combine the sets (of) A and B* is more eloquent than *we combine (both) A and B sets*; however, either could be used.